# play2 [2.1.2-scala Is it possible to change the scala version a play 2 project uses, i.e. upgrade from scala 2.10.0 to 2.10.2

Tags: playframework-2.1

Is it possible to do that, so that I see sth. like the following:

```
       _            _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/

play! 2.1.2 (using Java 1.7.0_25 and Scala 2.10.2), http://www.playframework.org
```

Or is that not supported, i.e. for compatibility reasons?

I tried setting it in the build file directly, i.e.:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    scalacOptions += "-feature",
    resolvers += "Big Bee Consultants" at "http://repo.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/repo",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.2"
  ).dependsOn(common).aggregate(common)
```

but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution via a hint from the google group, see it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework-dev/vXbkCEvJrkQ

The solution is to actually set the scala version in the build file like posted in the question above. The play sbt plugin does not show the correct scala version but if you type the "console" command in sbt you will see the correct scala version.

This has only tested if you run play from sbt directly. I do not know if it works with a downloaded play framework zip file.

Also I'm still not 100% convinced that it uses that version to compile the stuff.

Comment: As one can see in the reply in the forum topic posted above it really changes the version! It's just not printed.